# Small pull requests and compatible branching model

Tags: git, branching-and-merging, pull-request

So it is good practice to have small pull requests to make life easier for everyone. What I am wondering is how does the branching look like to be able to make these small pull requests.

Lets say I have a development branch and I create a new feature branch from the development branch. I make my commits on the feature branch until the feature is finished and then submit a pull request. Now the pull request might contain a huge amount of changes and that is what we do not want.

Is the solution for this so make a pull request for each reasonable change in the feature branch, although this might "pollute" the development branch with unfinished code from the feature, or is this fine.

Another way might be to have a second feature-dev branch where you create your smaller pull requests into the feature branch and then, if the whole feature is finished, you create a final pull request from the feature branch into the development branch. Since all changes have already been reviewed during the pull requests from the feature-dev into feature branch we can just merge it. This feels like it creates overhead, but might be fine if multiple people are working on the same feature and have their own feature-dev branches they create pull requests from into the feature branch.

Answer (score 0):

How about you branch out feature branch from the master and make the feature branch the default branch, so that you branch out each feature of your application from the feature branch so that each feature you build and create a public request it will be compared with the feature branch. After testing the feature merged to the feature branch you can then merge to master branch. That's what my work flow looks like #cheers